# Angular routing & Bootstrap - Display a modal dialog without changing the content of the page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Using Angular routing & Bootstrap.

**How can i display a modal-dialog without changing the content of the page?**

I tried this , but the browser (Chrome) keep getting Stucked.

**Links :**

```
<a href="#Home">Home</a>
<a href="#postModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Post</a>
<a href="#Profile">Profile</a>
```

**Angular :**

```
<script>

var currentUrl="";
var currentCtrl="";

var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/Profile", {
            templateUrl : "london.html",
            controller : "londonCtrl"
        })
        .when("/postModal", {
            templateUrl : currentUrl,
            controller : currentCtrl
        })
        .otherwise({
            templateUrl : "paris.html",
            controller : "parisCtrl"
        });
});
app.controller("londonCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.msg = "I love London";

    var init = function() {
        currentUrl  = "london.html";
        currentCtrl = "london.html";
    } ;
    init();

});
app.controller("parisCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.msg = "I love Paris";

    var init = function() {
        currentUrl  = "paris.html";
        currentCtrl = "parisCtrl";
    } ;
    init();
});
```

**The dialog:**

```
<div id="postModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            Update Status
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="form center-block">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea id="textareaPost"autofocus="autofocus" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="What do you want to share?" ></textarea>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="permission" value="Public" checked> Public
                <input type="radio" name="permission" value="Private"> Priavte
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" onclick="onClickButtonPostSubmit();">Post</button>
                <ul class="pull-left list-inline">
                    <li><a href="" onclick="onClickPostUpload();"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i></a></li>
                    <!-- <li><a href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i></a></li>     -->
                    <!-- <li><a href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i></a></li> -->
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What i'm doing wrong? 
Perhaps there is a better way..

Thanks

Comment: what is the problem you are facing? also angular ui router is for navigation. Do you want to use it for modal window?

Comment: I need to use the navigation. But when I use the bootstrap model-dialog, the navigation changed..

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK remove your browser history and check it

:)

Comment: done. Sadly, nothing has changed -  the tab froze when i click on the href of the dialog. .